# Does Summary Fields extension work on 4.6.x

Tags: extension, summaryfields

The [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) extension is listed as working with 4.4 and 4.5. I am testing it on 4.6.8 and when I go to the Summary Fields tab for a contact that does have some Contribution records I see blankness. I have debug and backtrace on but am not seeing any errors as such. I haven't used this Extension before so it is possible I am just not using it correctly. Does anyone have this working on 4.6 or is it known to fail?

Comment: I've tested in 4.6.8 and don't have the same experience. Are you getting a white screen of death? Or, do you mean that none of the fields on the Summary Fields tab are filled in for a given record? Are you sure the given contact has contributions with the status set to complete? Have you tried re-generating the summary fields (go to Administer -> Custom Data and Settings -> Summary fields and re-submit the form?

Comment: Jamie, are you okay if I edit the Extension description and add a new second paragraph that reads eg "Once the Extension is installed, visit Administer > Customise > Summary Fields, and select the fields you want displayed." That was the only issue for me, I hadn't found this!

Comment: Yes - that patch would be quite welcome Peter. Many thanks.

Comment: ok done (but my sentence needs to be a bit longer to be accepted)

Answer (score 1):

I use Summary Fields on several 4.6 sites with no issues.  Also - "Jamie" who left the comment is the author of Summary Fields, I'd follow their suggestion!

Comment: Thanks Jon for sharing this info - it's helpful to know. We plan to roll out 4.6 over the next few weeks. Assuming all goes well, I'll officially update the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to use Summary Fields in a 4.6 Drupal installed CiviCRM and had an issue. I don't know any details of why, but it did load the Summary pages successfully, but took literally a couple of minutes for each page to load.

I am also holding back on upgrading a larger CiviCRM install at a non-profit purely because Summary Fields doesn't explicitly support the latest CiviCRM and my experience trying to install on this other site.